# Change gravity header in table layout Android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, gravity

I have this

```
 public void header(int recursocabecera)
{
    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutCelda;
    TableRow fila = new TableRow(actividad);
    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutFila = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    fila.setLayoutParams(layoutFila);

    String[] arraycabecera = rs.getStringArray(recursocabecera);
    COLUMNAS = arraycabecera.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < arraycabecera.length; i++)
    {
        TextView texto = new TextView(actividad);
       // layoutCelda = new TableRow.LayoutParams(obtenerAncho(arraycabecera[i]), LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
       layoutCelda = new TableRow.LayoutParams(obtenerAnchoPixelesTexto(arraycabecera[i]), LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
     //   layoutCelda= new LayoutParams(100, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        texto.setSingleLine(true);
        texto.setText(arraycabecera[i]);
        texto.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        texto.setRotation(-90);
        texto.setTextAppearance(actividad, R.style.estilo_celda2);
        texto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabla_celda_cabecera2);
        texto.setLayoutParams(layoutCelda);
        texto.setPadding(20,0,0,100);
        layoutCelda.setMargins(0,0,60,0);
        layoutCelda.setMarginEnd(90);

        fila.addView(texto);
    }

    tabla.addView(fila);
    filas.add(fila);

    FILAS++;
}
```

the result is somenthing like that
[image]

but  I need it to be something like this

[image]

setGravity it works half, but the titles are shown cropped

My result:

[image]

Comment: Could you show the error image ?

Comment: I added it in my post. Thanks